# Serverless framework AWS Codebuild completed successfully(?) but no APIGateway or lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

thanks in advance for any help.
I'm new to Serverless and Serverless framework.

I'm trying a CI/CD pipeline for the first time.
I have ran the serverless.yml in the offline environment and I have functional CRUD operations in local debug and a healthy DynamoDB table.

The pipeline is AWS CodeCommit->CodeBuild->CodePipeLine

The pipeline flows without error but there are no lambdas or APIGateway present in the output.

I'm hoping it is a simple switch somewhere or some such?

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing serverless...
        npm install -g serverless


  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Install npm source dependencies...
        npm install

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment started on `date`...
        echo Deploying with the Serverless Framework...
        sls deploy -v -s $ENV_NAME

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment completed on `date`...
```

serverless.yml

```
service: sls-notes-backend
frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  -
    serverless-offline

custom:
  allowedHeaders:
    - Accpet
    - Content-Type
    - Content-Length
    - Authorization
    - X-Amz-Date
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - X-Amz-User-Agent
    - app_user_id
    - app_user_name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: us-east-1
  stage: prod
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5
  endpointType: regional
  environment:
    NOTES_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    -
      Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeletItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.NOTES_TABLE}"

functions:
  add-note:
    handler: api/add-note.handler
    description: POST /note
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: note
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:  ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  update-note:
    handler: api/update-note.handler
    description: PATCH /note
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: note
          method: patch
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:  ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  get-notes:
    handler: api/get-notes.handler
    description: GET /note
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: notes
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:  ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  get-note:
    handler: api/get-note.handler
    description: GET /note/n/{note_id}
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: note/n/{note_id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:  ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  delete-note:
    handler: api/delete-note.handler
    description: DELETE /note
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: note/t/{timestamp}
          method: delete
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:  ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

resources:
  Resources:
    NotesTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.NOTES_TABLE}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: user_id
            AttributeType: S

          -
            AttributeName: timestamp
            AttributeType: N

          -
            AttributeName: note_id
            AttributeType: S

        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: user_id
            KeyType: HASH

          -
            AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE

        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: note_id-index
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: note_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

CODEBUILD LOG:

```
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:03 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:05 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src664645733/src
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src664645733/src/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 No runtime version selected in buildspec.
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src664645733/src
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Registering with agent
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phases found in YAML: 4
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06  INSTALL: 1 commands
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06  PRE_BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06  BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06  POST_BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Running command echo Installing serverless... npm install -g serverless
Installing serverless... npm install -g serverless

[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Running command echo Install npm source dependencies... npm install
Install npm source dependencies... npm install

[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Running command echo Deployment started on `date`... echo Deploying with the Serverless Framework... sls deploy -v -s $ENV_NAME
Deployment started on Sat Mar 6 07:51:06 UTC 2021... echo Deploying with the Serverless Framework... sls deploy -v -s prod

[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Running command echo Deployment completed on `date`...
Deployment completed on Sat Mar 6 07:51:06 UTC 2021...

[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

Comment: I’ve faced something similar; turned out my console region was us-east-2, but I was deploying to us-east-1, so when I was looking I didn’t see the resources, because my console session was the wrong region... Maybe you’re facing the same..?

Comment: Me too, but not on this occasion everything points to us-east-1

Comment: When you say `the pipeline flows without error`, how do you know this? What do the logs of the build execution show you?

Comment: Thanks hephalump, the CodeBuild log for the latest build doesn't indicate any problem areas and the pipeline transitions to build succeeded. Codebuild log to follow, portably missed something important...

Comment: Tough to read these as comments; if you could edit your question and add the full build execution logs that would help and I’m sure we’ll find the issue.

Comment: For sure the build commands aren’t executing; note the timestamps. Looking at your buildspec, the commands and the `-` appear to be on separate lines; is this a Stackoverflow/copy+paste issue, or how it actually looks?

Comment: First of all sorry for not getting back to you sooner, I'm a constant quiet user of overflow but this is one of the few occasions that I've needed to post. I checked and rechecked the page but for some reason your post didn''t come through the refresh, frustrating. This is how it looks. This was deliberate as it resolved some issues in the serverless offline build. I'll reformat the code and attempt another build.

Comment: Still no juice. Would it be possible to confirm with me about how the timestamp is indicative of no execution i.e. that the build rattles through all the commands synchronously and a healthy build would be much more asynchronous?

Comment: The timestamp seems to indicate that the commands are not executing; the `npm install -g serverless` command is completing in <1 second, and the entire build is completing in 3 seconds... Serverless compiles to CloudFormation so if we consider that a stack update via CloudFormation has to take place, and you can infer that your container commands are not actually executing. Sidenote, if you’re not using your own image in CodeBuild, make sure you select a container runtime environment https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

Comment: Thanks hephalump, I'll run these docker images locally and try to reproduce the code build output.

Comment: `[Container] 2021/03/06 07:51:06 No runtime version selected in buildspec.`
This usually produces an error for me. Just add the runtime version to your buildspec as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html

Comment: Hephalump :) yoo tha mhain... runtime spec and I started getting errors and eventually a gateway and lambdas, thank you. I've amended the Buildspec.yml to the functioning version for anyones future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I should be a bit embarrassed because after the errors started coming I looked more closely at the yml spec and found that those ticks hephalump mentioned early on were really important as without one the yml continues on the echo command from the previous line meaning the entire Buildspec reduce itself to one big string.  I've posted the Buildspec.yml to the functioning version for anyones future reference.

Thanks to Hephalump the correct Buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - echo Installing serverless...
      - npm install -g serverless
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Install npm source dependencies...
      - npm install

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment started on `date`...
      - echo Deploying with the Serverless Framework...
      - sls deploy -v -s $ENV_NAME
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment completed on `date`...
```